# How can I open another google sheet within the same folder from within google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am starting with google app script...

Within google app script in a google sheet, what might be the simplest way to open another google sheet within the same folder if I just know the name of this other google sheet

I am struggling to find a concept of "current folder" from within the Spreadsheet class.

Many things seem to work by FileId rather than name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve Google Spreadsheet in the same folder with the active Spreadsheet using the Spreadsheet title.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your active Spreadsheet, set `spreadsheetTitle` you want to use, and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetTitle = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet title you want to retrieve.

  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(activeSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents().next();
  const files = parentFolder.searchFiles(`title='${spreadsheetTitle}' and mimeType='${MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}' and trashed=false`);
  if (!files.hasNext()) {
    console.log(`No spreadsheet with '${spreadsheetTitle}'is found.`);
    return;
  }
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next());

  console.log(ss.getId()); // As a sample. the spreadsheet ID of the retrieved Spreadsheet is shown in the log.

  const valuesOf1tab = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(valuesOf1tab); // As a sample. the values of 1st tab from the retrieved Spreadsheet is shown in the log.
}
```

- When this script is run, when the spreadsheet of `spreadsheetTitle` is found, you can see the spreadsheet ID in the log. When the spreadsheet of `spreadsheetTitle` is not found, you can see `No spreadsheet with '###' is found.` in the log.
- In this sample script, it supposes that the spreadsheet of `spreadsheetTitle` is only one in the parent folder of the active spreadsheet. But, when there are multiple spreadsheets with the same filenames, the following sample script might be able to be used.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    const spreadsheetTitle = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet title you want to retrieve.

    const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(activeSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents().next();
    const files = parentFolder.searchFiles(`title='${spreadsheetTitle}' and mimeType='${MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}' and trashed=false`);
    const spreadsheets = [];
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      spreadsheets.push(SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next()))
    }
    if (spreadsheets.length == 0) {
      console.log(`No spreadsheets with '${spreadsheetTitle}'is found.`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`${spreadsheets.length} spreadsheets were found.`);
    spreadsheets.forEach(ss => {
      console.log(ss.getId()); // As a sample. the spreadsheet ID of the retrieved Spreadsheet is shown in the log.
      const valuesOf1tab = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
      console.log(valuesOf1tab); // As a sample. the values of 1st tab from the retrieved Spreadsheet is shown in the log.
    });
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchfilesparams)
- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getParents())

Comment: How can this be done without giving the Google Apps Script access to do whatever it wants to every file and folder in Drive?

Comment: @Joe White About your question of `How can this be done without giving the Google Apps Script access to do whatever it wants to every file and folder in Drive?`, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, this is not your question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.
Note: must enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services before executing.

```
function retrieveFileObject(strFilename) {
  try {
    var fileList = DriveApp.getFilesByName(strFilename);
    if (fileList.hasNext()) {
      // found matching file - log it
      var objFile = fileList.next();
      var myString = "The file that was found is: " + objFile.getName();
      Logger.log(myString);
      return objFile;
    }
  }

  catch(err) {
    Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}


function exampleOpenGoogleSheet() {

  var objSheetFile = retrieveFileObject("myFileName");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(objSheetFile);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("mySheetName");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log("This is the value in cell A1: ", data[0][0]);
}
```